# Can you use jQuery .css() with .live()?

Tags: live, jquery

I have a `div` with `class="centerMessage"` . This `div` is inserted into the DOM at a point after the page is loaded. I would like to change the CSS on this `div` to center it. I tried the CSS function below, but it did not work. Does anybody know a way to do this?

```
function centerPopup() {
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var positionLeft = (winWidth/2) - (($('.centerMessage').width())/2);
var positionTop = (winHeight/2) - (($('.centerMessage').height())/2);
$('.centerMessage').live( function(){
$(this).css("position","absolute");
$(this).css("top",positionTop + "px");
$(this).css("left",positionLeft + "px");
});
}
```

Comment: The ".live()" facility is about handling events; there's no event involved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my assumption of what you're trying to achieve is correct, you don't need any Javascript to do this. It can be achieved by some simple CSS.

```
.centerMessage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px; /* half of the height */
    margin-left: -300px; /* half of the width */
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/awuja4

Answer (score 1):

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) does not accept JUST a function. If you want something to happen with live, it needs an event as well, like `click`. If you want something to happen always for every `.centerMessage`, you will need the plugin [.livequery()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following works in FF & Webkit.

```
div.centerMessage{
    position: absolute;
    width: /* width */;
    height: /* height */;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: That won't work.  The "margin: auto" part is OK, but it only works when you're not doing absolute positioning.

Comment: yeah, thats true, the thing is that this is a absolutely positioned div. It does not flow in line with the other content.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered, but I thought I'd provide a ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fnjpE/)*** using JavaScript like the OP originally wanted, but instead of using **live()**, I use **setInterval()**:

First, we need to declare a couple variables for use later:

```
var $centerMessage,
    intervalId;
```

The OP's issue was that they didn't know when the div was going to be created, so with that in mind we create a function to do just that and call it via **setTimeout()** to simulate this div creation:

```
function createDiv() {

    $('<div class="centerMessage">Center Message Div</div>').appendTo("body");

}

$(function() { setTimeout("createDiv()", 5000); });
```

Finally, we need to create a function that will check, using **setInterval()** at a rate of 100ms, to see if the div has been created and upon creation, goes about modifying the div via jQuery:

```
function checkForDiv() {

    $centerMessage = $('.centerMessage');

    if ($centerMessage.length) {

        clearInterval(intervalId);

        var $window = $(window),
            winHeight = $window.height(),
            winWidth = $window.width(),
            positionTop = (winHeight / 2) - ($centerMessage.height() / 2),
            positionLeft = (winWidth / 2) - ($centerMessage.width() / 2);


        $centerMessage.css({

            "display" : "block",
            "position" : "absolute",
            "top" : positionTop.toString() + "px",
            "left" : positionLeft.toString() + "px"

        });

    }

}

$(function() { intervalId = setInterval(checkForDiv, 100); });
```

Comment: If i do really want to create stylesheet rules on the fly with javascript which can apply to elements not in the DOM yet, i can simple add css rules to a programmatically created style tag and append it to the head.

Comment: @Lorefnon - You do understand that you just downvoted an answer that is a year and a half old, don't you?  Also, you do understand that this answer is simply providing a working version of what the OP was trying to accomplish originally, don't you?  What you are suggesting is *another* alternate way of accomplishing the goal.  Alternate solutions are not by default wrong.  My solution works and is only an alternate solution to show it can be done with jQuery/JavaScript, as the OP was originally working with.

Comment: Not to incite a flame war here, but your answer as it stands provides a crude solution and although it does solve the example scenario presented by chromedude it does not resolve the actual problem class. What happens if i add another element with class 'centerMessage'. Your solution does not add the css properties to this element because you have expired the counter.Jquery.live would have taken care of events triggered on any object matching the selector added at any point in future. Given the title of question an analogous behaviour would be expected in this scenario as well.

Comment: Leaving the loop running forever is not a sensible thing to do simply because the moment you have several such loops performance will begin to degrade - for no good reason. Jquery.live definitely does not do a similar kind of thing for exactly this reason. Rather an event being bubbled up is watched in a parent element guaranteed to be present eg. Body.

Comment: Given the fact you were the most reputed answerer in the thread and the fact that despite being a year old the question is relevant and may be regularly viewed by thousands of newcomers i believe that offering them a mediocre suboptimal solution might be misleading.

Comment: @Lorefnon - The OP did not ask how to handle multiple elements with `.centerMessage`.  You need not put words into their mouths and downvote based on a scenario which was not presented.  Obviously, if the scenario was different, so would the solution.  Again, it answers the EXACT scenario the OP gave and was working in.  You sir, are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try Use this

$('.centerMessage').live('click', function(){

Comment: Please elaborate the answer. It is helpful but it will be clearer than this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});

$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

OR

```
$('#foo').live('click', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});

$('#foo').trigger('click');
```